# Control flow efficiency

Tags: cuda, control-flow

As stated in the Branch statistic [manual](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/developertools/desktop/analysis/report/cudaexperiments/kernellevel/branchstatistics.htm), there are two metrics: branch efficiency and control flow efficiency.

The former has a hardware counter `branch_efficiency`. However, it seems that there is no direct hardware counter for the latter. Is it possible to find the ratio of executed and issued control flow instructions and use that as the second efficiency metric? Or the control flow utilization metric `cf_fu_utilization`?

Since control flow efficiency can be interpreted as the number of threads that are active for one instruction in a warp, I guess that `warp_execution_efficiency` can also be used since the definition says

> Ratio of the average active threads per warp to the maximum number of threads per warp supported on a multiprocessor

Any comment on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both branch efficiency and control flow efficiency are metrics. Branch efficiency can be collected in a single psd and is shown as per SM values. Control flow efficiency is smsp__thread_inst_executed / smsp__inst_executed / WARP_SIZE * 100.0. These counters cannot be collected from all SMs in a single pass on all hardware so the metric is shown on the chart as an average across all SMs.

If using CUPTI/NVPROF the hardware events are:

- inst_executed: Number of instructions executed per warp.
  WARNING: The description states "per warp". This should be the sum.
- thread_inst_executed:  Number of instructions executed by the active threads. For each instruction it increments by number of threads, including predicated-off threads, that execute the instruction. It does not include replays.
- not_predicated_off_thread_inst_executed:  Number of thread instructions executed that are not predicated off

These events can be used to calculate either average_threads_executed_per_inst_executed or average_threads_executed_not_predicated_off_per_inst_executed. This can be converted to a % by / 32 x 100.0.

The compiler will use predication instead of a branch if the body of the conditional is small (several instructions).

Comment: Branch efficiency is reported by nvprof. So, 100% for a kernel that is invoked 10 times means that for all 10 invocations, 32 thread was active with no divergent branches. What is the hardware metric for `smsp__thread_inst_executed`?

Comment: Correct. If you launched a odd number of threads per block you would see the value reduced even if you have no control flow in the kernel. I updated the answer with the hardware counters and formulas for nvprof/CUPTI.

Comment: Regarding `inst_executed`, nvprof reports a number, e g. 100, for a kernel that is invoked 50 times. So, I assume that is the total number of retired instructions for 50 times from all threads. Isn't that? Otherwise, I have to know what is the number of warps in invocations.

Comment: I don't see any metric for the second and third bullet. I mean here https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#metrics-reference

Comment: The document lists metrics. It does not list events. Run nvprof --query-events to list all of the events. inst_executed event returns the sum of all instructions executed (retired) on all SMs for 1 grid launch. If you want instructions executed per warp the formula is inst_executed / warps_launched. The UI will print the event name then min, max, avg, total. These are calculated across all launches of the same kernel and are at at grid/GPU level for min/max/avg and total is the sum of all launches.